# Run Command When USB Device Connected

Tags: usb, mount

I have a USB flash drive plugged in to my Ubuntu Server machine most of the time. It has an entry in `/etc/fstab` which mounts it to `/mnt/foo` after being identified by UUID. It mounts fine on boot and when

```
sudo mount -a
```

is run. But, if I disconnect and reconnect the device [physically], it'll be recognised (as in *shown in `lsblk`*), but not mounted.

I have a backup script that copies files to `/mnt/foo`, so it needs to be mounted there as soon as it's connected. How do I mount this USB automatically when it's connected (and on boot)?

Comment: You can make Cron job(as root) who runs `mount -a` all 5mins

Comment: @lucki1000 I would rather not run a command on a loop in the background. Primarily because I'd like it to be mounted as soon as the drive is plugged in.

Comment: Read `man -k udev`. `udev` is designed to make this kind of task (recognize a particular USB and Do Something) "easy".

Comment: @waltinator I've tried making udev rules before. The syntax and all is correct, but nothing works. Is there something I'm missing?